# Dont understand how to derive function $u(ct+x_0,t)$ with restect to $t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm watching a online tutorial [Transport equation, derivation at 9:35](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hG1r1PA6T4w&list=PLmsGGxFhM5bzUCRCjQbQtolk-yzB2eFqn&index=2) it states the following

Let $u$ be a function of $x,t$
$$\frac{d}{dt}u(ct+x_0,t) = \frac{\partial u(ct+x_0,t)}{\partial x}\frac{d(ct+x_0)}{dt}+\frac{\partial u(ct+x_0,t)}{\partial t}\frac{d(t)}{dt}$$
I don't understand why the derivative of $u$ with respect to $t$ contains a
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ term when derivation is only with respect to $t$.

Could anyone explain this derivation ?

Comment: Read about the Chain Rule in several variables. That's exactly what you have here...

Comment: Oh sure, yes it's multi variable chain rule. I've got it now. Thanks